# Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides but for ASP.NET webforms

Tags: webforms, reverse-proxy

ASP.NET core has a middleware called Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides that can automatically replace the content of HTTP request header RemoteIpAddress, Scheme, and Host with the content of X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Proto, and X-Forwarded-Host request headers.

This is useful when the web server is under a load balancer, so the application can still generate redirects, links, etc. with correct value.

Is there similar tool for ASP.NET webforms?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this? I'm running into the same issue with a legacy app I'm attempting to move to AWS behind a load balancer.

Comment: @Joreyaesh not resolved yet